# Automatic Coercion of Dates in R

Tags: r, date

Has this always worked in R or is it recent behavior?

```
Sys.Date() == "2018-04-27"
[1] TRUE
```

In what other situations would the string "2018-04-27" automatically be converted to the date type?

Comment: It has been documented somewhere, can't recollect now. It also works in this case : `1 == "1"`.

Comment: This behaviour is documented in `?Ops.Date`.

Comment: Although , the question in the marked duplicate is of `int` but I think it gives a proper explanation for this case as well.